# Knap sack: Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

We are given the knapsack problem, such that the user can only carry weight $W$ and no. of items available is $n$.

Note: We cannot split the items which means cannot take 1.5 of item 1 for example.

The textbook says...

Using dynamic programming the problem can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(nW)$
time, which is reasonable when $W$ is small, but is not polynomial since the input size is $\propto log\ W$ rather than $W$.

My question is why is the input size proportional to $log\ W$ instead of $W$.

Comment: You may want to look up pseudopolynomial time algorithms. The size of the input takes into account the binary representation of $W$, not just the number itself. Since you can represent $W$ in $\log W$ bits, the input size is proportional to $\log W$.

Comment: Specifically, it is 'pseudo' polynomial because while $O(nW)$ looks polynomial in the input variables $n$ and $W$, since we represent $W$ by $\log W$ bits, $W$ is _exponential_ with respect to the length $\log W$, and _not_ polynomial. I also feel like the line "... which is reasonable when $W$ is small..." a bit misleading here - most any complexity is reasonable on small input sizes.